# java println output encoding on windows

Tags: java, windows, character-encoding

This question originates from a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230478/utf-8-unicodedecodeerror-on-windows-but-not-on-os-x). There were suggestions that this may be a Java problem instead so I posted another question.

What determines the output encoding of the system.out.println command? Basically, I'm executing a python program from command prompt, which spawns a child process running java(stanford parser) It takes my input document encoded in UTF-8, processes and println my input in specific formats. Back at the python program, I could not decode the output from stdout with utf-8. This works on OSX so I'm suspecting it could be a console encoding issue.

I have tried setting `chcp 65001` and changing the font type but these does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses the [default encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset--) which on Windows will be an obsolete "ANSI" encoding. The documented way to change this is "via the operating system" though this is as far as it goes. You can also call [System.setOut](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) to provide your own mechanism:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"));
```

See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html) for more depth.

Comment: so you meant that on windows the default encoding is ansi while on Unix shell it's whatever the enc type is .? what do you mean via the operating system then?

Comment: The documentation doesn't say exactly how you're supposed to change the encoding, just that it should happen outside the VM - it's an implementation detail and not that helpful. For example, on Linux it might use the $LANG variable. There is no documented way to change it in Windows as far as I am aware. Windows carries a lot of legacy. You can change STDOUT encoding using code (see above) or via the unsupported `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` system property.